# unnest list in python

Tags: python, json, regex, list

I have a JSON list that I'm calling from a db, but gets formatted like this:

```
[('[{"recommendation": "Fung Corp"}, {"recommendation": "AllSeq"}, {"recommendation": "Testing testing org"}]',)]
```

I want to unnest it so the leading `[('` and trailing `,)]` so all remains is the actual JSON list of objects

```
[{"recommendation": "Fung Corp"}, {"recommendation": "AllSeq"}, {"recommendation": "Testing testing org"}]
```

All in python preferably

Comment: This should help:[literal_eval](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this

```
db = [('[{"recommendation": "Fung Corp"}, {"recommendation": "AllSeq"}, {"recommendation": "Testing testing org"}]',)]
print(db[0][0])
```

result,

```
[{"recommendation": "Fung Corp"}, {"recommendation": "AllSeq"}, {"recommendation": "Testing testing org"}]
```